# How to make a CentOS linux server for Active Directory

Tags: centos, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a linux server at my home with **CentOS** and I would like to make it a Domain Controller for Active Directory.

**Is there a way to make it?**

I don't wanna use **Windows Server 2008 R2** 'cause it's Windows and I need some linux-only tools. Or I can make a virtual machine in linux to run *WS2K8*. If I understand how in *VMware vSphere*!

Comment: Why do you need to use Linux only software with an AD DC? Also, since this is clearly about your home environment, this question is OT here, please see our [FAQ].

Comment: It's for my home, but my office is at my home, there's why. But I need Linux only tools for other thing like VMs but I really need AD DC for my 7 computers, and the 8 others of my office and home, merged.

Comment: So build an AD server, and join the CentOS box as a member server.  If you need AD, you need AD, not a beta-re-implementation on an unsupported OS>

Comment: @jscott LOL, but CentOS support member-server level ofr AD ? I didn't know but thanks! (Post it as an answer.)

Comment: I run Windows 2008 r2 inside wirtualbox on my home network.  Works like a champ.

Comment: @uSlackr Indeed, but I have only 2GB of RAM on my computer, so I need a separate computer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want installing [samba](http://www.samba.org/) on your server and configuring it to acting as a Domain Controller, but keep in mind that *though a domain controller configuration can be achieved with a simple configuration using the new tdbsam password backend, this type of configuration is good for small offices, but has limited scalability (cannot be replicated), and performance can be expected to fall as the size and complexity of the domain increases.*

Take a look at [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/centos-5.x-samba-domain-controller-with-ldap-backend) tutorial that explains well how to proceed to setup samba as Domain Controller on CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Samba as a domain controller on linux.  The recipe & details are here: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/samba-pdc.html

Answer (score 0):

I will just run **Windows Server 2008 R2** for AD and a virtual machine with VMware for **CentOS** and another one for my test web server.

3 Servers in one!